# How to create multiple alert in same time using ARM template

Tags: json, azure, templates, azure-rm-template, azure-log-analytics

I want to configure Log Analytics alert using ARM templates so just following given link:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-monitor/insights/solutions-resources-searches-alerts#sample

But problem is, I am working on a requirement to create CPU, Memory and Disk alert. And for this I need to write 3 different ARM with different KQL.  Could you please help me to edit this given template to achieve my requirement to generate all alert using single ARM.

If I will create 3 different template then the major problem is I will have 3 solution under my Log Analytics as this template is creating solution for each alert. So just looking for a way to edit this template in such a way to configure multiple alert using single template.

Below is the template that i want to edit: -

```html
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0",
    "parameters": {
      "workspaceName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "Description": "Name of Log Analytics workspace"
        }
      },
      "workspaceregionId": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "Description": "Region of Log Analytics workspace"
        }
      },
      "actiongroup": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "Description": "List of action groups for alert actions separated by semicolon"
        }
      }
    },
    "variables": {
      "SolutionName": "SolutionTest",
      "SolutionVersion": "1.0",
      "SolutionPublisher": "SolutionTesters",
      "ProductName": "SolutionTest1",

      "LogAnalyticsApiVersion": "2017-03-03-preview",

      "MySearch": {
        "displayName": "Processor over 70%",
        "query": 'Perf | where ObjectName=="Processor" and CounterName=="% Processor Time" and CounterValue>70',
        "category": "Samples",
        "name": "Samples-Count of data"
      },
      "MyAlert": {
        "Name": "[toLower(concat('myalert-',uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, deployment().name)))]",
        "DisplayName": "Processor over 70%",
        "Description": "Processor alert.  Fires when 3 error records found over hour interval.",
        "Severity": "critical",
        "ThresholdOperator": "gt",
        "ThresholdValue": 70,
        "Schedule": {
          "Name": "[toLower(concat('myschedule-',uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, deployment().name)))]",
          "Interval": 15,
          "TimeSpan": 60
        },
        "MetricsTrigger": {
          "TriggerCondition": "Consecutive",
          "Operator": "gt",
          "Value": 3
        },
        "ThrottleMinutes": 60,
        "AzNsNotification": {
          "GroupIds": [
            "[parameters('actiongroup')]"
          ],
          "CustomEmailSubject": "Sample alert for processor query"
        }
      }
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "name": "[concat(variables('SolutionName'), '[' ,parameters('workspacename'), ']')]",
        "location": "[parameters('workspaceRegionId')]",
        "tags": { },
        "type": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions",
        "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches', parameters('workspacename'), variables('MySearch').Name)]",
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches/schedules', parameters('workspacename'), variables('MySearch').Name, variables('MyAlert').Schedule.Name)]",
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches/schedules/actions', parameters('workspacename'), variables('MySearch').Name, variables('MyAlert').Schedule.Name, variables('MyAlert').Name)]",
        ],
        "properties": {
          "workspaceResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', parameters('workspacename'))]",
          "referencedResources": [
          ],
          "containedResources": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches', parameters('workspacename'), variables('MySearch').Name)]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches/schedules', parameters('workspacename'), variables('MySearch').Name, variables('MyAlert').Schedule.Name)]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches/schedules/actions', parameters('workspacename'), variables('MySearch').Name, variables('MyAlert').Schedule.Name, variables('MyAlert').Name)]"
          ]
        },
        "plan": {
          "name": "[concat(variables('SolutionName'), '[' ,parameters('workspaceName'), ']')]",
          "Version": "[variables('SolutionVersion')]",
          "product": "[variables('ProductName')]",
          "publisher": "[variables('SolutionPublisher')]",
          "promotionCode": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('workspaceName'), '/', variables('MySearch').Name)]",
        "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('LogAnalyticsApiVersion')]",
        "dependsOn": [ ],
        "tags": { },
        "properties": {
          "etag": "*",
          "query": "[variables('MySearch').query]",
          "displayName": "[variables('MySearch').displayName]",
          "category": "[variables('MySearch').category]"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('workspaceName'), '/', variables('MySearch').Name, '/', variables('MyAlert').Schedule.Name)]",
        "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches/schedules/",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('LogAnalyticsApiVersion')]",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[concat('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspaceName'), '/savedSearches/', variables('MySearch').Name)]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "etag": "*",
          "interval": "[variables('MyAlert').Schedule.Interval]",
          "queryTimeSpan": "[variables('MyAlert').Schedule.TimeSpan]",
          "enabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('workspaceName'), '/', variables('MySearch').Name, '/',  variables('MyAlert').Schedule.Name, '/',  variables('MyAlert').Name)]",
        "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/savedSearches/schedules/actions",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('LogAnalyticsApiVersion')]",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[concat('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspaceName'), '/savedSearches/',  variables('MySearch').Name, '/schedules/', variables('MyAlert').Schedule.Name)]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "etag": "*",
          "Type": "Alert",
          "Name": "[variables('MyAlert').DisplayName]",
          "Description": "[variables('MyAlert').Description]",
          "Severity": "[variables('MyAlert').Severity]",
          "Threshold": {
            "Operator": "[variables('MyAlert').ThresholdOperator]",
            "Value": "[variables('MyAlert').ThresholdValue]",
            "MetricsTrigger": {
              "TriggerCondition": "[variables('MyAlert').MetricsTrigger.TriggerCondition]",
              "Operator": "[variables('MyAlert').MetricsTrigger.Operator]",
              "Value": "[variables('MyAlert').MetricsTrigger.Value]"
            }
          },
          "Throttling": {
            "DurationInMinutes": "[variables('MyAlert').ThrottleMinutes]"
          },
        "AzNsNotification": {
          "GroupIds": "[variables('MyAlert').AzNsNotification.GroupIds]",
          "CustomEmailSubject": "[variables('MyAlert').AzNsNotification.CustomEmailSubject]"
        }             
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

How could I add Memory, Disk alert in above template.

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I cant decipher what you are asking, can you rephrase?

Comment: Generally, I want to create multiple alert using single ARM template. How could i achieve this where i need to modify this template.
I have requirement to create a template for CPU, Memory and Disk alert.
So I am good with KQL and Log Analytics however not sure how to create a single template for this.

If I would go with the option which is defined in above link then i will have multiple solution for each alert and I need to create multiple templates too. Because this template is creating a solution for every alert.

Comment: so whats preventing you, you can just copy\paste them

Comment: I want to configure Log Analytics alert using ARM templates so just following given link

But problem is, I am working on a requirement to create CPU, Memory and Disk alert. And for this I need to write 3 different ARM with different KQL.  Could you please help me to edit this given template to achieve my requirement to generate all alert using single ARM.

Comment: If I will create 3 different template then the major problem is I will have 3 solution under my Log Analytics as this template is creating solution for each alert. So just looking for a way to edit this template in such a way to configure multiple alert using single template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the copy element for resource type. But still you need to create alerts variables. For example if you want to create 3 alerts you will need three variable arrays with different values within them. You need to manage the resources using the IDs dynamically.

Follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple